# AS3 Optimising FLV hiding

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flv

Is there any great memory or CPU difference for the following 2 bits of code?
Basically hiding an flv or completely removing it, then reloading it when required.

Option 1 (hide)

```
public function stopFlyby():void {

flvPlaybak.seek(0);
flvPlaybak.stop();
flvPlaybak.visible = false;

}
```

then to see again

```
public function playFlyby():void {

flvPlaybak.visible = true;
flvPlaybak.play();

}
```

Option 2 (remove)

```
public function stopFlyby():void {

flvPlaybak.seek(0);
flvPlaybak.stop();
removeChild(flvPlaybak);
flvPlaybak = null;

}

public function playFlyby():void {

flvPlaybak = new FLVPlayback(); 
//load flv...
addChild(flvPlaybak);
flvPlaybak.play();

}
```

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am no expert on the subject but since no one has answered yet I'll throw my 2 cents in.

Option 1 has an advantage of not having to download the video file again, which for some videos could take a while; however, there's a chance the browser's cache might come to the rescue and prevent it from having to be downloaded again.

Option 2 would free up memory (whenever garbage collection feels like it of course :) and since it is a video it would likely be a good amount of memory freed up.

As far as the CPU goes I would assume the difference between the options is hardly noticeable to the end user.

I lean toward option 2, since likely after the user watches the video once they won't want to watch it again.

Comment: todd is right i think. but you should ask yourself whether or not it is likely that the user wants to watch the video again ... it'll be cacheed but there will be small delay before the video can be shown again. option 1 enables you to replay the video faster ... but maybe `flvplayback.pause()` is better than `stop()`.

Comment: Thanks. We'll assume that's the correct answer unless we hear different.